# Linked dropdown doesn't seem to work under IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have two drop down lists - the second of which is updated based on an option being selected in the first.

After testing these on IE8, I found out that the second drop down list does not update at all when the first is changed! It remains empty!

How do I fix this? It works perfectly fine under Chrome and Firefox.

jQuery

```
$("#dept").on("change blur", function () {
        var dept = $("#dept").val();
        var dataString = 'dept=' + dept;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_dept.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#moduleCode').html(html);
            }
                });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_moduleCode.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#moduleName').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that only the `document` has a ready function, so :

```
$("#dept").ready(function () { ...
```

is really not valid at all, it's more suprising that it actually does work in some browsers ?

From the [**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the
>   current document, so the selector can be omitted.

maybe it should be:

```
$("#dept").on('change', function () { ...
```

if you're trying to bind the ajax functions to whenever the `#dept` element changes, and I'm assuming that the drop downs are `select` elements.

Comment: @adeno I've changed it but still no luck - removing all traces of ready hasn't done anything and yea I am using dropdowns

Comment: Funny question considering, but did you wrap it all in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Yes I have - I've pasted all my JavaScript code here: http://pastebin.com/3s6BizRE